# How can I change execution level authorization at runtime?

Tags: uac, nsis, elevated-privileges

I have `RequestExecutionLevel user` at the start, because usually I install on user level.

But I want to change it afterwards, if some condition is detected, to admin. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execution level ([Integrity Level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_Integrity_Control)) of a Windows process is determined when the process starts and cannot be changed after the process has started.

While it might be possible to use the [UAC plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UAC_plug-in) to get around this, I would actually recommend that you use `RequestExecutionLevel highest` and gray out whatever option that requires admin rights for standard users...